# How to negate or cancel CSS `hue-rotate` on SVG tags?

Tags: css, svg

There are a lot of questions about this problem already asked on Stack Overflow. However, I couldn't find the answer to my specific question. (Maybe I'm missing something obvious, and somebody can point me to the answer.)

The simplest way to activate the Dark mode on a page is by applying `filter:invert(1)hue-rotate(180deg)` to the whole `html` tag. However, it will also affect the `svg` tags changing their colors. Unfortunately, you cannot apply the same `filter` to `svg` elements, since `hue-rotate` is not additive, leading to wrong colors (like in the example below).

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{background-color:white}
html{filter:invert(1)hue-rotate(180deg)}
svg{filter:invert(1)hue-rotate(180deg)}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg>
<rect width="42" height="42" x=" 0" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0)" />
<rect width="42" height="42" x="42" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0)" />
<rect width="42" height="42" x="84" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to apply this `filter` to all elements of the page except `svg` tags (and their contents) by only modifying the CSS code?

Comment: Generally it is bad practice to go against the cascading part of css, however you could remove the hue-rotation and just invert it a second time. A simple alternate way to create a dark mode would be to use [css custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). You could have a background color, text color, etc. and then update their values with javascript.

Comment: @Jordan I know that it can be achieved with JS, but my question is if it is possible with CSS only.

Comment: How are you planning to switch between dark and light mode then? If it's always dark mode then you can use the custom properties to quickly change the colors and keep track of them.

Comment: *The simplest way to activate the Dark mode on a page is by applying filter:invert(1)hue-rotate(180deg)* --> that's wrong. It's actually a hacky very bad way to do it. You just discovered one issue among many

Comment: @Jordan I don't plan to switch to the Light mode. I need to enable Dark mode in Jupyter Notebook by modifying `custom.css` file. (And I don't want to install any themes that can do it.)

Comment: Alright, then I would still recommend using css custom properties to make it easy to modify the file.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know that `hue-rotate` is not a good command. Is there a right way to do it in CSS only?

Comment: @Jordan Sorry, I don't understand, how it can work, if I cannot modify the whole HTML page.

Comment: in `custom.css`, you should define the custom properties in the [root psuedo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root#declaring_global_css_variables). You would reference the variables throughout your code by using `var(--variable_name)` and it would effect the page.